# Should I build my Haskell app via the RPM SPEC file or try to use a (reproducible) binary from the CI pipeline

Tags: rpm

I haven't built an RPM from scratch in 20 years. So we can effectively say "never".

[edit] The requirement for RPMs is to provide roll-backs, version control, and such. It is non-negotiable.

I have a single binary and a single config file I need to install. There's some setup with user accounts and directories that needs to happen that I believe should be straight forward.

If I want a tested reproducible build in the RPM build process I have to replicate our CI pipeline steps. Non-trivial. Ideally I can just pull in the desired files from some other location:

```
%prep
cp ${somefile} ${another file} $RPM_SOURCE_DIR
%setup
:
```

Is this possible? Or am I missing some obvious solution.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From my point of view, it depends a bit what you're targetting exactly:

Linux distributions like Fedora actually expect for their distribution builds that the software is built from source using the spec file (inside a sealed buildsystem that's also documenting the packages/components used for building) and consider this a good practice, also to gain as much reproducibility as possible.

However, you indeed can just pull pre-built binaries and use them inside a spec file to build a RPM package, shortened example for your scenario:

```
# […]
Source0: <binary file>
Source1: <config file>

# […]

%prep
%setup -q -c -T

%build

%install
install -D -p -m 0755 %{SOURCE0} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_bindir}/%{name}
install -D -p -m 0644 %{SOURCE1} $RPM_BUILD_ROOT%{_sysconfdir}/%{name}.conf

# […]
```

While this might work, you should explicitly check whether the dependencies of the resulting RPM package are suitable (`rpm -qp --requires <…>.rpm`) or if there are missing run-time dependencies. Often there are compile-time options or parameters (e.g. `CFLAGS` or `LDFLAGS` software written in C) as well as post-processing scripts (e.g. `/usr/lib/rpm/(redhat/)brp-*`) while building the RPM package that add distribution specific stuff and/or extract run-time dependencies for you. This may or may not be relevant for you (and some post-processing scripts also might work for pre-built binaries but other do not due to lack of compiler options). While I'm packaging a lot of software, I'm not experienced with Haskell, but when looking to some Fedora packages, there are RPM packages having run-time dependencies (and if there are run-time dependencies these have to be satisfied by RPM packages, because that's how RPM works; and it's not enough to have the matching library somewhere on your filesystem, because RPM will not know about it except it's provided by a RPM package). Thus, building a RPM package from pre-built binaries might lead to a RPM package without proper dependencies which might reveal as run-time errors later.

Regarding the above example: While `SourceX:` can be given a URL, `rpmbuild` still expects these files on-disk in the `SOURCES` directory when building the RPM package (so how they're getting into the `SOURCES` directory is up to you).

Given you didn't mention which Linux distribution you're targetting, I'm linking Fedora's [Haskell Packaging Guidelines](https://docs.fedoraproject.org/en-US/packaging-guidelines/Haskell/)
 here, which may or may not provide further inspiration. And yes, RPM packages can be cross-distribution, which practically often leads to static binaries inside the RPM packages, due to often different library/package versions on different Linux distributions.